# Why is the matrix not incrementing even after an explicit line written to do the same in numpy?

Tags: python, matrix, logistic-regression

```
def inti():
    ini = {'theta' : np.array((1e6 , 1e7 , 1e7, 1e7 , 1e7) , dtype = 'float64').reshape(5 , 1) , 
       'b' : 1.2}
    return ini

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)) 

def net_input(theta, x):
# Computes the weighted sum of inputs
    return np.dot(x , theta)

def prob(theta , x):
    return sigmoid(np.array(net_input(theta , x)) + inti()['b'])

def loss(theta , x , y):
    temp1 = np.dot(y.T , np.log(prob(theta , x)))
    temp2 = np.dot((1- y).T ,(1 - np.log(pdef grad(theta , x , y):
    return (np.dot(x.T , prob(theta , x ) - y))
    #temp = (-1/m)* temp
    return ((-1/m)* temp[0])

def grad(theta , x , y):
    return (np.dot(x.T , prob(theta , x ) - y))

cost =[]
#inti()
def params(x , y , theta , learning_rate):
    theta = inti()['theta']
    for i in np.arange(10000):
        cost.append((loss(theta , x, y)))
        theta = theta + (learning_rate) * grad(theta , x , y)
        print(grad(theta , x, y))
    return theta
# Function to get theta matrix 
parameters = params(X_train , y_train , inti()['theta'] , 20)`
```

I am a beginner in Python and ML and have a written the above functions to execute Logistic Regression. All the matrix dimensions are properly defined in the way that no error occurs in the matrix multiplication. 
I am facing rather an uncanny issue here. The theta matrix wont' just increase. I printed the cost of every epoch to see how well the initialization was but the cost came out to be same all the time without the gradient matrix being zero too. The gradient matrix also was constant at every epoch.

I thought it was maybe because of the low learning rate. But even after increasing the learning rate to 20 I find it is not changing.

I have looked over the code and it seems logically correct.

The matrix dimensions are
X_train : (700 , 5)
y_train : (700 , 1)
theta : (5 , 1)

Comment: your code has syntax errors

Comment: But it works fine. Could you please point out the error?

Comment: I mean code you posted has errors check once and update the post

Comment: I have checked and it compiles perfectly on Jupyter Notebook!